# How to set a condition in SharePoint using Power Automate to require an uploaded file to have a minimum of 3 tags chosen from a custom column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

How to set a condition in SharePoint using Power Automate to require an uploaded file to have a minimum of 3 tags chosen from a custom column? How would the flow looks like, I can't really figure it out.

I want to do this because I am creating a file storage management environment where people have to choose a minimum of 3 tags so that people are thinking actively what the files are meant for to be able to search for them more easily in the future.

I tried to use the colomn value which should be greater or equal to 3 followed by an condition but I dont really understand how this works. When the taggs are 3 or greater the person should be able to upload the document and if not the person will receive an error message on the SharePoint page.

Comment: did you try the trick of adding a description I described in my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use Power Automate to do validation like this. The Power Automate flow only runs after the action in SharePoint has completed, not while the action in SharePoint is in progress.

You might be able to do this using a list validation formula (part of the list settings), but I'm not aware of a way to get the count of a multiselect choice or lookup field using this technique.

Comment: Is it possible to upload a file and just give the person who uploaded the file a kind of reminder to select 3 taggs? So without any validations but just a friendly reminder message. (Not with an email but just in screen)

Answer (score 0):

- **Power Automage cloud flow**  (when an item is created) cannot be a solution as it's an ansynchronous flow, and cannot block a user to add an item without the 3 mandatorys tags ;

[image: when an item is created]

- **Validation settings** (a built-in feature in SharePoint to check if an item is valid or not) cannot be used as tags (taxonomy field) are not compatible with validation formula ;

[image: Validation settings]

- One *simple* solution is to add a description below the field to inform the user that 3 tags are required. But it will not block a user to add an item without the 3 tags...

Configuration:

[image: field description]

Result:

[image: form]